# item images get mixed after listview scrolls down

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

i have an activity to show user contacts list. if contact exists in my app i want to show a follow button , else i want to show a whatsapp and telegram icon to invite them.

when i open the activity every thing is fine as i want , but when i scroll down and come back up follow buttons and whats app icons get mixed for different contacts ! the users who had follow button may see whatsapp icon or the others may see follow button !
and everytime i scroll down and up again positions will change !

i should say all contacts name and mobile number are fixed and correct ! just images get mixed !

i know the problem is from my getView function but dont know how to fix it :(
how can i fix it ? tnx :)

Here is all of my adapter code :

```
public class LazyAdapterContactsList extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public ImageLoader profileImageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> song;
public LazyAdapterContactsList(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    profileImageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(vi==null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.listID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactslistIDPosition);
        holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactslistName); 
        holder.mobile = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactslistMobileNumber);
        holder.whatsAppIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactsListWhatsApp);
        holder.telegramIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactsListTelegram);
        holder.followBtn = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactsListFollowBtn);
        holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactsthumbnail);

        holder.profile_thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.MyContactslist_image_profilephoto);




        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();          
    }



    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    holder.listID.setText(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_ID));
    holder.name.setText(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_NAME));
    holder.mobile.setText(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_MOBILE));


if (song.get(MyContacts.KEY_USER_EXISTS).equals("1")) 
{


       if (song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL).equals("no")) {

        } else {
            profileImageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL), holder.profile_thumb_image);
        }


        }else {

            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.followBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    return vi;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView ,listID ,name,mobile;
    public ImageView whatsAppIcon ,telegramIcon;
    public Button followBtn;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public ImageView profile_thumb_image;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever action you do with any view of ListView like `HIDE` or `VISIBLE` in condition **(if)**, you must have to set opposite `HIDE` or `VISIBLE` in opposite condition **(else)**.

Try this solution just change code as per below:

```
   if (song.get(MyContacts.KEY_USER_EXISTS).equals("1"))
    {
        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.followBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL).equals("no")) {

        } else {
            profileImageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL), holder.profile_thumb_image);
        }


    }else {

        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.followBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: tnx this change fixed the problem for icons :)  but a problem still exists for this code :

Comment: profileImageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL), holder.profile_thumb_image);

Comment: it downloads contacts images from server . but still after scrolling contacts profile photo are mixed with eachother !

Comment: i added a photo . can you please check it?

Comment: What is code inside `if (song.get(MyContacts.KEY_THUMB_PROFILE_URL).equals("no")){` function.

Comment: its empty ! actually i just needed the else part !

Comment: in xml layout i have seted  a default source image from drawable folder. do i need to set them again?

Comment: Make a default URI with default image and try set that in empty condition and check it.

Comment: Not a problem, just set default image to `holder.profile_thumb_image` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, use floatingaction button. The position of the button will remain same, and you wouldn't feel annoyed

Comment: no , i have some thing like instagram follow buttons . if a user is followed i dont need to show the button again and i make it invisible .

Comment: Would you like to show a common follow button for the list page or for individual row?

Comment: for indiviual row , (the contacts who are not followed yet )    . i show it correctly but after scrolling they get mixed and some users had follow button will dont have and vise versa.

Comment: add click on listner using context to the follow button, in the on click method make it invisible. And one more thing, you should set the preference for each user to check the user is already followed. Otherwise you wouldn't have any track on which of the users followed and not followed.  Use SQLLITE or Sharedpreference

Comment: i get it from server , dont have problem with that. i added a photo of what happens to profile photos can you please look at it? tnx.

Comment: hey, still i didn't understand? photo is just displayed at the right of each rows. If you've any problems with loading images directly from the server, you could user any other libraries like picasa, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144836/discussion-between-visal-varghese-and-saeid).

Answer (score 0):

You view gets reused/recycled from system - so you have to (re)set `profile_thumb_image` every time in getView.

If not, there is a chance that you get a recycled view where the image was set in a previous call of getView.

Answer (score 0):

First don't make this variable global

HashMap song;

Take this into ur getView() method if possible make it final.

As @coyer told

You view gets reused/recycled from system - so you have to (re)set profile_thumb_image every time in getView

Hope this help u...if any questions u can ask